# How to manually install a VSCode extension on SSH box?

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code

I edit code on a remote SSH host with a Remote Development extension. The code is mostly in Python, so I would naturally like to use Python extension for things like "go to definition", linting, and such.

However, when I open Python extension in VSCode locally, there is this button "Install in SSH: my-host-machine". When I press it, it shows "Installing..." for some time, and then silently fails. I can't fix it because I see no stderr output to know what's wrong.

My question is, how can I manually install a VSCode extension to my SSH box where the VSCode server runs? That way I'll know why it fails to install and will be able to fix it.

I need something like `code --install-extension /path/to/vsix`, but executable on my SSH box rather than on my local machine.

Comment: install locally and copy the extension directory to the ssh machine, if the language server is also part of it I don't know

Comment: On the marketplace page of the extension is a download link on the right

Answer (score 6):

I know you said you want a command but here's what I did to manually install.

1. I downloaded it from marketplace and copied it over onto my ssh machine example: `/root/ms-python.python-2020.5.86398.vsix`
2. Than on my local machine I chose the option to install from VSIX and it showed me the remote SSH machine path
3. I selected my VSIX file and pressed ok and it started installing and it installed after 5 mins, very slow process.
   After installation it asked for reload and it worked.